# Modify Spring data Page<> class projection response in service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, projection

I am using projection, and I need to format the date variable in list of objects, but Page<> type response is read only, so I can not iterate and modify the objects. What Should I do?

```
@Override
public Page<OrderDto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return OrderDao.findByIsEnabledTrue(pageable, OrderDto.class);
}
```

I tried like this:

```
@Override
public Page<OrderDto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {

    Page<OrderDto> page = orderDao.findByIsEnabledTrue(pageable, OrderDto.class);

    List<OrderDto> orderDtos = page.getContent();

    orderDtos.stream().forEach(it ->{
        it.setFormattedCreatedAt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy").format(it.getCreatedAt()));
    });

    page.getContent().clear();
    page.getContent().addAll(orderDtos);

    return page;
}
```

Comment: Are you returning Page<OrderDto> itself from your controller method and don't want to change that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

page.getContent() returns an unmodifiable list. The best approach is to use map method provided by `page`:

```
@Override
public Page<OrderDto> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
  Page<OrderDto> page = orderDao.findByIsEnabledTrue(pageable, OrderDto.class);
  page = page.map(this :: transformOrderDto);
  return page;
}

private OrderDto transformOrderDto(final OrderDto order) {
  order. setFormattedCreatedAt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy").format(order.getCreatedAt()));
  return order;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.10, `Page` has supported [a `map` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) that is specifically meant to let you transform the objects contained in it.

Comment: I can get list of content but here problem is need to keep pagination response to frontend

Comment: @ShivaKumarN I can't understand what your comment means. This is exactly how you iterate and modify (replace) the items in a Page.

Comment: From the Page contents i can get by getContent() after modified not able to set to the Page,  :

Comment: You can check now, i tried like this,  i mean above question edited now